# Pymol: select low confidence regions from AlphaFold pdb file

Tags: protein-structure, pymol, structural-biology

I have downloaded a predicted structure from AlphaFold as a pdb file (https://alphafold.com/entry/O75376) and loaded it into Pymol (2.3.0). There is quite a large portion of the structure that was modelled with very low confidence (pLDDT < 50). Is there a way to select these regions in the structure so that I can assign a different representation to them? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Answer from @matteo-ferla, converted from [comment](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment):*

They are stored as b-factors. This is well described in the [PyMol wiki](https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Selection_Algebra).

*[please edit to improve this answer, if possible]*

Answer (score -1):

use:
Spectrum b, Red_white_blue

Comment: It is not clear what this means.